# How to take user input from one react component and use it to generate a portion of a json file in a different react component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

On a word game start page, a user can select a number between 5-8 from a drop-down menu. I need to use their selected number in the game play component to generate a random set of words that have the same length as their selection from sets of words stored in a json file. I'll then need to display the random selection on the play page.

I have created the drop down, and made it so they can select a number. I don't know how to take that number and get the words from the json file that relate to their selection, and display one of the words that's relevant.

Here's a link that describes what I'm trying to accomplish:
https://www.webucator.com/project/play2learn-single-page-application/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) are also recommended.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.